# How to get the pdf of this transformation $Y=|X|$?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, density-function

This question is from George Casella textbook question 8.30(b). $$f(x\mid\theta)=\frac{\theta}{\pi}\frac{1}{\theta^2+x^2},\quad -\infty<x<\infty,\, \theta>0$$

Let $ Y=|X|$, how to get the pdf of $Y$? I know theorem 2.1.15, but it requires that $Y=g(X)$, where $g$ is a monotone function. Here I have $ Y=|X|$, obviously it is not monotone. So I am stuck here.

Here is the solution:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This case is discussed in Chapter 2 of Casella.  You would simply write
$$\Pr[Y \le y] = \Pr[|X| \le y] = \Pr[-y \le X \le y] = \int_{x=-y}^y \frac{\theta}{\pi} \frac{1}{\theta^2 + x^2} \, dx.$$  Note since $f(x \mid \theta) = f(-x \mid \theta)$ for all $x$, we can also write this as $$\Pr[Y \le y] = 2 \Pr[0 \le X \le y],$$ hence $$f_Y(y \mid \theta) = 2 f_X(y \mid \theta) \mathbb 1 (y \ge 0).$$

Comment: Thanks!, But do you mean $\Pr[Y \le y] = 2 \Pr[0 \le X \le y]$?

Comment: @Yichuan yes, I omitted the 0 by mistake.  I will make the correction.

Comment: Thanks. Now I understand. By using this way, I can use Fundamental Theorem of Calculus (page 287) to get pdf. Also, another route to get $\Pr[Y \le y] = 2 \Pr[0 \le X \le y],$, is due to the function inside integral is even function. So it's from calculus I.